# PostgreSQL: `NEW.<value>` returning `NULL` when `AFTER TRIGGER` is fired

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-13

#### Description of the problem:

Hi everyone, i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPORDINE (
    CodProdotto CHAR(5) NOT NULL CHECK(CodProdotto ~* '^[0-9]+$'),
    CodOrdine CHAR(5) CHECK(CodOrdine ~* '^[0-9]+$'),
    Prezzo REAL NOT NULL, CHECK(Prezzo >= 0.0)
    CONSTRAINT OrdineFK FOREIGN KEY(CodOrdine) REFERENCES ORDINE(CodOrdine)
    CONSTRAINT ProdottoFK FOREIGN KEY(CodProdotto) REFERENCES PRODOTTO(CodProdotto)
);
```

on which I declared a `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatePrezzoOrdine
AFTER INSERT ON COMPORDINE
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE updatePrezzoOrdine();
```

and a `TRIGGER FUNCTION`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatePrezzoOrdine()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
  Totale REAL;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(Prezzo) INTO Totale
  FROM COMPORDINE AS CO
  WHERE CO.CodOrdine = NEW.CodOrdine
  GROUP BY CodOrdine;
  UPDATE ORDINE SET PrezzoTotale = PrezzoTotale + Totale
  WHERE CodOrdine = NEW.CodOrdine;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$
```

Everything works and the trigger just fires fine, but no `UPDATE` is done on table `ORDINE` (on line 12).

#### What I experience (and tried):

I've tried to put some print instructions to see if the query was working:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'NEW.CodOrdine = %', NEW.CodOrdine;
RAISE NOTICE 'NEW.CodProdotto = %', NEW.CodProdotto;
RAISE NOTICE 'NEW.Prezzo = %', NEW.Prezzo;
```

but the output returns that new row inserted:

```
INSERT INTO COMPORDINE VALUES ('12345', '11111', 1.80)
```

has null values:

```
NOTICE: NEW.CodOrdine = <NULL>
NOTICE: NEW.CodProdotto = <NULL>
NOTICE: NEW.Prezzo = <NULL>
```

So the `UPDATE` "fails" because no row in `ORDINE` matches `NULL` values:

| **CodOrdine** | **PrezzoTotale** | **DataAcquisto** | **CodCliente** | **CodDipendente** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | default (0.0) | 2020-12-12 | 00000 | 99999 |

Apparently the problem could be related to the inserted row, may it?

#### What I expect:

After `INSERT` I would the `ORDINE.PrezzoTotale` column to be updated with the correct total price of every item in `COMPORDINE` that matches `COMPORDINE.CodOrdine = ORDINE.CodOrdine` in this way:

```
INSERT INTO COMPORDINE VALUES ('12345', '11111', 1.80)
```

| **CodOrdine** | **PrezzoTotale** | **DataAcquisto** | **CodCliente** | **CodDipendente** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1.80 | 2020-12-12 | 00000 | 99999 |

Big thanks to anyone in advance

#### [EDIT #1]:

As asked, here's the output of `\d compordine`:

```
**"public.compordine" table:**

|   Colonna  |     Tipo     | Ordinamento | Pu‗ essere null | Default|
|------------|--------------|-------------|-----------------|--------|
|codprodotto | character(5) |             | not null        |        |
|codordine   | character(5) |             | not null        |        |
|prezzo      | real         |             | not null        |        |

**Indexes**:
    "compordine_codprodotto_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (codprodotto)

**Check constraints**:
    "compordine_codordine_check" CHECK (codordine ~* '^[0-9]+$'::text)
    "compordine_codprodotto_check" CHECK (codprodotto ~* '^[0-9]+$'::text)
    "compordine_prezzo_check" CHECK (prezzo > 0::double precision)

**Referential integrity constraints**:
    "ordinefk" FOREIGN KEY (codordine) REFERENCES ordine(codordine) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    "prodottofk" FOREIGN KEY (codprodotto) REFERENCES prodotto(codprodotto) ON UPDATE CASCADE

**Triggers**:
    updateprezzoordine AFTER INSERT ON compordine FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION updateprezzoordine()

**Disabled triggers**:
    updatescorte BEFORE INSERT ON compordine FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION updatescorte()
```

#### [EDIT #2]:

So, I did several other attempts to find a solution (**SPOILER ALERT**: no solution found); what I did, was to create another function and trigger that simply prints the `NEW.<column>` value after an `INSERT` statement on a different table called `CLIENTE` (my suspect was that all this issue was releated only to `COMPORDINE` table but I was wrong), here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
    CodCliente CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, CHECK(CodCliente ~* '^[0-9]+$'),
    Nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHECK(Nome ~* '^[A-Za-z ]+$'),
    Cognome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHECK(Cognome ~* '^[A-Za-z ]+$'),
    CodiceFiscale CHAR(16) NOT NULL, CHECK(CodiceFiscale ~* '^[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$'),
    Indirizzo VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHECK(Email ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-za-z]+$'),
    UNIQUE(CodiceFiscale, Email)
);

CREATE TRIGGER print
BEFORE INSERT ON Cliente
EXECUTE PROCEDURE print();

CREATE FUNCTION print()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'CodCliente = %', NEW.CodCliente;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$

INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES ('34567', 'Gianfranco', 'Rana', 'GNFRNA87F24E123A', 'Via Delle Rane 23', 'franco.rane@ravioli.it')
```

Output returns:

```
NEW.CodCliente = <NULL>
```

While it should be:

```
NEW.CodCliente = <34567>
```

I simply can't understand why, shouldn't `NEW` in an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` returns the value this way? :

| **Event** | `OLD` | `NEW` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `INSERT` | `NULL` | New Record |
| `DELETE` | Old Record | `NULL` |
| `UPDATE` | Original Record | Updated Record |

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing sum over one table isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: Are there any other triggers or rules on the table? Please add the output of `\d compordine` run in `psql` to the question.

Comment: @stickybit Ok, got it and all, but why the `NEW` values are empty?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe here you are

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code, and I cannot reproduce the error. The `RAISE NOTICE` in my trigger do not print NULL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Maybe this issue is caused by the fact that another function is defined on COMPORDINE? But what's stranger is that the other function I am speaking of, works flawlessly

Comment: If you mean `updatescorte()`, the trigger that fires it is shown as disabled and it would not be working at all.  Where did you put the `RAISE NOTICE` statements in the code? I could not replicate with a similar trigger. FYI, this would have easier to follow and debug with a consistent naming style. I spent a good bit of time confirming there was not a quoting issue with things like `CO.CodOrdine = NEW.CodOrdine` and actual field name `codordine`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver No, I am not refering to `updateScorte()` but to `updatePrezzoOrdine()` I know that the trigger releted to `updateScorte()` is disabled, so this is not a problem. Anyway I inserted the `RAISE NOTICE` instructions into `updatePrezzoOrdine()`, just to verify if the values were correct, for debugging purpose. I am sorry for the formatting, but the code in edited part was generated automatically from psql, not my fault

Comment: The `psql` code is not the problem, it is correct. The issue is all the CamelCase stuff in the rest of code. Since it is not quoted it all gets folded down to lower case. The possible issue is case where an identifier got quoted and is retains the mixed case. Are there any messages in the Postgres log aroun the time the `INSERT` is done that might relate to this?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver how can i check that?

Comment: Not sure what OS you are using, but on Unixen you can `tail` the file, do the INSERT and see what appears.

Comment: My DB is stored on AWS so I don't know if that could be possibile

Comment: @AdrianKlaver by the way, I don't think that the problem could be related to case sensitive (Postgre should not be case sensitive, to write SQL statements in upper case it's just a convention) because, my other function, `updateScorte()` (before I disabled the related trigger), works and follows the "same logic" of `updatePrezzoOrdine()`: `SELECT ... WHERE <table name>.CodProdotto = NEW.CodProdotto` and `NEW.CodProdotto` isn't `NULL`. I just can't understand what's going on

Comment: AWS log information [Logging](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/working-with-rds-and-aurora-postgresql-logs-part-2/).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you. I checked, no errors found in log.

Comment: Then I don't know where to go from here. The `NEW.*` is showing as `NULL` so that indicates to me that there are no values present in the `INSERT`. You will need to figure out that can be?

Comment: And you would be perfectly right, but after the `INSERT` postgre console shows `INSERT 0 1` sign that the statement has been executed correctly, indeed querying on the `COMPORDINE` table returns the inserted value. I wanted to export the DB on another machine, maybe a local laptop with linux on it, just to see if the issue still comes up. You know any way to export the DB in another machine?

Comment: As for me, adding of these lines of code are worked: 'FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION func_name'

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. For me the issue was the way I created the trigger:

```
create trigger pending_balance_add after insert on pending_balance 
execute function update_pending_balance();
```

I forgot to tell that "**for each row**" and perhaps "**procedure**" instead of **function**:

```
create trigger pending_balance_add before insert on pending_balance 
for each row 
execute procedure update_pending_balance();
```

Now inside of update_pending_balance I have correct new.amount, etc.

Regarding your issue, it shows that

**Triggers**:
updateprezzoordine AFTER INSERT ON compordine **FOR EACH STATEMENT** EXECUTE FUNCTION updateprezzoordine()

**Disabled triggers**:
updatescorte BEFORE INSERT ON compordine FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION updatescorte()

**When trigger is executed for statement it has NEW.FIELD values as NULL**

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL Can't change values in AFTER trigger. Change the trigger to BEFORE.
Does not matter if you change the variable record NEW, the data was already changed in the table record. AFTER triggers ignore NEW changes. You can read and write but only read matters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I changed tigger to before, the same issue arises.

Comment: Can you show the trigger code?